# I want to raise a question about the notation of Dini derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The four Dini derivatives are:
$$ D^+F(x) = \limsup_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}, \\ D^-F(x) = \limsup_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = \limsup_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{F(x)-F(x-h)}{h}, \\ D_+F(x) = \liminf_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}, \\ D_-F(x) = \liminf_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = \liminf_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{F(x)-F(x-h)}{h}$$
Now I wonder what is the $D^+(-F(-x))$?
My instructor claimed that $D^+(-F(-x)) = D^-F(x)$, but I think $D^+(-F(-x)) = D^-F(-x)$.
So which is correct? This troubles me and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: By $D^+(-F(-x))$ do you mean $D^+(G(x))$ where the function $G$ is defined by $G(x)=-F(-x))$? Or do you mean $D^+(H(-x))$ where $H(x)=-F(x)$? Or something else?